# Docker not using correct version from requirements.txt

Tags: docker

I have updated a version in my requirements.txt file. After deploying my docker `docker-compose.yml` again, python/docker is still using the old version.

After some googling around I did following things, but they didn't help:

- docker builder prune
- RUN pip install -r /etc/aggregators/requirements.txt --no-cache-dir

This is the part in my Dockerfile where I install the requirements:

```
# Copy the config file and mongo certificate to the image
WORKDIR /etc/aggregators/
COPY config/${CONFIG_ENV}.pem mongo.pem
COPY requirements.txt .
COPY config/${CONFIG_ENV}.ini config.ini
COPY config/logging.conf .

# Install all of the python requirements in the image
RUN pip install -r /etc/aggregators/requirements.txt --no-cache-dir
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.2"
services:
  aggregator:
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        environement: development
    volumes:
      - ./:/aggregator
    depends_on:
      - mongodb

  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
```

Comment: `deploying my docker docker-compose.yml again, python/docker is still` deploying how exactly? How is docker-compose related?

Comment: 'Compose: docker-compose.yml' has been deployed successfully.

Comment: It's not related, docker just names it that way, I guess

Comment: How are you running the container; how do you verify that the package version isn't updated?  (Are `volumes:` or an explicit Python virtual environment involved?)

Comment: I verify it by go check in the code itself. I know what is updated. I will add my docker-compose.yml to the question. There is one volume that is my project itself